# Is it possible to unwind on panic in `#![no_std]` mode?

Tags: rust, panic, stack-unwinding

Is it possible to unwind on panic in `#![no_std]` mode, e.g. with a customized `#[panic_handler]`?

Comment: The following article from [phil-opp](https://os.phil-opp.com/freestanding-rust-binary/#panic-implementation) explains unwinding in a no-std environment,though you will have to use OS specific libraries like [libunwind](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/) on linux